# Exec-PHP WORDPRESS add number 1 after include

Tags: php, wordpress

i use in 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/
to write php code in my post
but if i write 
`echo 'S' ;`
this will print
`S`

but if i will write 
`echo include('2.php') ;`
and in `2.php` write "D"
this will write `D1` 
after all page that I include this add the number 1 
I want to delete it
how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

See below URL it is very help full to you.

Important Note:

Please see the URL. Many thing are there.

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/execute-php-in-wordpress-post-page-and-widget-sidebar/

**Execute PHP in WordPress post, page and Widget Sidebar**

**Executing PHP codes in WordPress Page/Post**

**Executing PHP codes in WordPress widget sidebar**

Or Try it:-

**Executing PHP codes in WordPress Page/Post**

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/execute-php-in-wordpress-post-page-and-widget-sidebar/

Installation

- Download [phpexec.txt](http://priyadi.net/wp-content/plugins/phpexec.txt)
- Rename phpexec.txt to phpexec.php
- Upload to /wp-content/plugins/ directory
- Activate the plug-in from WordPress administration menu

**Usage**

Anywhere in your post/pages where you want to execute a PHP Codes, insert  before your php codes and  your php codes.

```
<phpcode>  
    <?php  
        echo "Current date and time: ";  
        echo date("l dS of F Y h:i:s A");  
    ?>  
</phpcode>
```

**Security**

If you are running a blog with multiple users, you need to determine who can run this plug-in. Alter the settings in your Administration Menu. Options -> PHPExec